# How to create typescript module that can extend/purposely pollute the global context?

Tags: typescript

Consider this:

```js
// foo.ts
import someLogFunction from 'super-fancy-example-logger';
const log = someLogFunction.fancyLogger;
```

```js
// bar.ts
import 'foo';
log('Hello, World'); // error
```

Now, this doesn't work for some reason. What changes should be made for `log` function to be available for usage in `bar.ts`? How scalable it can be?

Comment: Why use modules if you don't want to use modules?

Comment: What the alternative then?

Comment: Import scripts on the page then pray they work together. Just like the g̶o̶o̶d̶ old times. Modules helped a lot with reducing the insanity of all of this by making the dependencies explicit and isolated.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a nice solution altogether.